# Bear yourself open– meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase **"bear yourself open"** mean to be more open?

In today's world, people are so closed off to each other, maybe if we **bore ourselves open**, we'd be happier as a collective.

Comment: Note: there's a homonym, "to bare," meaning to make open as in "I bared my feelings to you." This is not the word in the example sentence "... if we bore ourselves more open," since "bore" is the past tense of "bear," and "bared" is the past tense of "bare." But I wonder whether the author was led to a slightly odd construction by the association.

Comment: Where does that example come from, please?

If it's quote, who said it and in what context?

If it's constructed, what led you to it?

Comment: voted to close.  No source

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of **to bear** means to be brave in how you conduct yourself or your actions. It isn't commonly used, but I'd read your sentence as:

> Maybe if we were brave enough to be open [with each other], we'd be happier...

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, 'bear oneself' has the following meaning:

> : to move, stand, or behave in a specified way

(The meaning is from Merriam-Webster.)

For example,

> He always bore himself like a gentleman.

means 'he always behaves like a gentleman.'

So the question phrase 'bear ourselves open' can be interpreted as 'behave/stand ourselves open'.

Comment: Yes, the question phrase can be interpreted as 'behave/stand ourselves open' and if it is, how does that translate into English?

What does "behave/stand ourselves open" mean?